# Dictionary sort?

Tags: android, sorting, dictionary

hey, 
i have a dictionnary like
"key2","value2"
"key3","value3"
"key1","value1"

is it possible to sort it on value ?
If not, any other object can do same thing? (sort value on key/value pair)

Comment: I suggest you accept some answers from the questions you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, clearly you're talking about a `Map`.

It really depends on what `Map` you're using, You don't need to sort a `TreeMap`, coz it is already sorted.

For any other, You can get the keys using `map.keySet()` and use `Collections.sort()` to sort them. (Note, the map will remain the same, you'll get a `Set` containing all the key values)

Hope it helped.